# What's the meaning of the nontrivial zeros of Selberg zeta function?

Tags: nt.number-theory, finite-fields, zeta-functions, zeroes

In the case of arithmetic variety over finite field, the zero points of the Hasse-Weil zeta function reflect the pure weights (i.e. dimension). On the other hand, in the case of the Selberg zeta function, the nontrivial zero points are deduced from the Laplace operator and it seems to me that they are almost trivial. Is there any 
good interpretation of these zero points?

Comment: What do you mean by "they are almost trivial"?